# How to execute bash scrip from the Python?

Tags: python, bash

How can I execute the bash script from the python? I am using subprocess lib which works fine for the .exe but doesn't work for the .sh script.

```
subprocess.call(["executable.sh", inputFile, "outPutFileName"])
```

and this is the error I am receiving:

```
hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: You need `bash` to run a `bash` script. It does not come with Windows by default.

Comment: I am running this in Gitbash so it should work

Comment: I dont know exactly how gitbash works, but I guess you have to `call(["path/to/bash.exe", "executable.sh", inputFile, "outPutFileName"])`.

Answer (score 1):

Bash is a Unix shell, which is a command line interface for interacting with an operating system (OS).

Bash is available by default on Linux and macOS operating systems, but it does not come with Windows by default.